# How to configure a private Bitbucket repository so I could include a private package in composer.json?

Tags: git, oauth, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a private `Git` repository in `Bitbucket.org`. It consists of a `Laravel` project that is ready to be used as a `composer` `package`. I don't want to publish it, I just want to be able to use it my other `Laravel` project by including it in `composer.json`. I googled a lot for tutorials and questions/answers on stackoverflow but I still am not able to do that. Here is a part of my `composer.json` file that should be relevant:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "myprovider/mypackage": "*",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"repositories": {
    "myrepository": {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://bitbucket.org/me/myrepository/"
    }
},
```

I tried `composer require myprovider/mypackage:*`, but then I get an error `Could not fetch https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/me/myrepository?fields=-project%2C-owner, please create a bitbucket OAuth token to access private repos`. Since I actually created OAuth token before, I pasted the required `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret` but then I get this:

```
Invalid OAuth consumer provided.
This can have two reasons:
1. You are authenticating with a bitbucket username/password combination
2. You are using an OAuth consumer, but didn't configure a (dummy) callback url

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "?pagelen=100&fields=values.name%2Cvalues.target.hash%2Cnext&sort=-target.date" 
file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I am new to `Bitbucket`, how should I know if I configured everything properly?

A step by step configuration would be awesome, none of the ones I found online fit for my situation.

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/126-Composer-install-of-Private-Bitbucket-VCS-aka-Invalid-OAuth-consumer-provided.html) covers the configuration for bitbucket private repos.

Answer (score 18):

The following answer is my personal notes after following the instructions of [this blog post](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/126-Composer-install-of-Private-Bitbucket-VCS-aka-Invalid-OAuth-consumer-provided.html) and seeing it work.

Many thanks to gizmola for the blog post and to gview for the comment pointing to it.

Let's say that for you project `my-name/my-project` you want to get the private package `myprovider/my-private-package` hosted on bitbucket.

- login into bitbucket
- `bitbucket settings` > `access management` > `oauth`
- add oauth consumer

  - name: composer
  - callback: (required but not used) `http://example.com`
  - tick: this is a private consumer
  - tick: `permissions` > `repositories` > `read`
  - save
- get key and secret from `composer oauth consumer / user for private repos`
- open / create `~/.composer/auth.json` and make sure it has where you replace the `xxxxx` and `yyyyy`

  ```
  {
      "bitbucket-oauth": {
          "bitbucket.org": {
              "consumer-key": "xxxxx",
              "consumer-secret": "yyyyyy"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- add your package into your composer.json

  ```
  {
     "name" : "my-name/my-project",
     "description" : "my project",
     "repositories": [
         {
           "type": "git",
           "url":  "https://bitbucket.org/myprovider/my-private-package.git"
         }
     ],
     "require": {
         "myprovider/my-private-package": "*"
      }
  }
  ```

Remember that if the composer.json of the private package has not `minimum-stability` set (eg. to `dev`) it will not work.

Example of composer.json for `myprovider/my-private-package`

```
{
    "name": "myprovider/my-private-package",
    "description": "my private package",
    "keywords": ["private package", "private", "package"],
    "type": "package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "email": "john.doe@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {"psr-0": {"": "src"}},
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.4"
    }
}
```